# bug on RELEASE but not on DEBUG

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
std::string s("foo");
sprintf(buf,"%s",s);
```

Why at least under MSVC 2010 this line of code doesn't bug  in DEBUG, but bug in RELEASE ?

Comment: Why would you do that to begin with?

Comment: who put me -1 without any explanation ?? i believe it is interesting to understand why a typical bug like this can bypass the DEBUG mode

Comment: He should really use string streams instead or completely switch to C!

Comment: yes but it's for real time processing.. and sprintf is faster than c++ streams!

Comment: @Guillaume07: I didn't rank this with -1. However, compiling C++ for Debug target does not guarantee that it will find all bugs for you. In fact Debug doesn't find any bugs for you at all. Instead - unless you have changed the settings - it typically switches of optimizations and adds creation of debug symbols so that you can set break points and step through your code (simply speaking). I may have misunderstood you, though.

Comment: @Guillaume07 - for real-time processing you copy, not use `sprintf`.

Comment: @littleadv: it's just for example the real code is sprintf(buf,"%d=%s",nb,s.c_str()); sorry.

Comment: @Guillaume07: Still not very fast. `std::string` methods know up fron how many bytes need to be copied, whereas C routines have to check every character against \0. For pipelined CPU's, it's better if the loop check depends on data known early.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier expects a NULL terminated `char*`. You are passing in a `std::string` instance. If it works in DEBUG, that's just pure luck.

You should use:

```
std::string s("foo");
sprintf(buf, "%s", s.c_str());
```

This will extract a `char*` and ensure that the buffer is NULL terminated.

It is possible that in the runtime library `std::string` has different implementations for DEBUG and RELEASE. Try compiling using both settings, but adding debug symbols to the RELEASE build and then step through the code. Look at the memory location where `s` is stored. Is there any difference?

Comment: maybe but I believe there is no luck in computer science ;)

Comment: Luck as in that you are lucky(?) that the debug version of `std::string` was designed to contain a pointer to the string data at the first offset in the object's memory. In this case i think the library authors could have helped by putting in something else at the first memory offset in the object in the DEBUG build.

Answer (score 4):

Variadic functions like `sprintf()` are not strictly type safe, in that any argument type is accepted (at compile time) as part of the variadic argument set.

As the other answers have shown, `"%s"` is a format specifier that expects a `NULL` terminated character string.  Passing a std::string in this case, is likely undefined.

If it works in DEBUG mode, it is likely just "lucky" in that the implementation happens to print the correct result (likely stemming from a c-style cast of the std::string object to a character pointer).

Answer (score 3):

That shouldn't work. Its likely that you are hitting undefined behavior.

```
std::string s("foo");
sprintf(buf,"%s",s.c_str());
```

You should actually probably be using streams instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is wrong. You should be writing this:

```
std::string s("foo");
sprintf(buf,"%s",s.c_str());
```

An object of type `std::string` cannot be passed to `sprintf` as there is no format specifier corresponds to `std::string`. Also, `%s` expects object of type `char*` or `char[]`, and `c_str()` function returns `char*`, so the above would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to mix up c and c++ then (for performance reasons, based on the comment you gave) then its a good idea to wrap the functions in c++ to avoid these subtle bugs.

```
struct console_out
{
  static void 
  print(const string& s)
  {
    sprintf(buf, "%s", s.c_str());
  }
  //other overloads should you want them
}
```

Be careful once and let the compiler be careful thereafter.

I sometimes think bugs like this are too easy in c and c++, but we can muddle through.