# Printing std::string via printf() in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, std

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  std::string s = "12345678";
  std::printf("[%s]\n", s);
}
```

Here is an obvious typo of missing ".c_str()". But VS2011 even with /Wall doesn't emit any warnings, and the program works. If to compile this code in gcc, it says "warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct std::string' through '...'; call will abort at runtime" and the program crashes with "Illegal instruction".

Did they really implement a trick in VS STL to make programs having such typo working just because this typo is very common?

**UPDATE**: The question is why it works in VS?

Comment: I don't know about `std::string`, but their pre-standard `CString` was designed so that it could be passed in this way.  I think it would actually work with the g++ implementation, if the compiler didn't intentionally insert code which would cause a crash.

Comment: Is there a question here?  Is it asking what the did or did not do in visual studio for this case, or what they did in gcc?

Comment: Kevin: the question is why it works in VS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820330/bug-on-release-but-not-on-debug - did you try in release mode?

Comment: I very much doubt this actually works -- it is definitely UB, and likely corrupts the stack, your sample program just terminates immediately afterwards so there's no opportunity to observe that corruption.

Comment: may be visual studio's library makes an overload of `printf` with `std::string`

Comment: @Mat: For me it does work regardless using /O0 or /O2 in 64-bit mode (no crash) but it doesn't work (crashes) in 32-bit mode (again, regardless of /O0 or /O2 flags).

Comment: Well, there you go. Garden variety Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: Casting 's' to 'char *' is a syntax error.

Comment: @Alexander I missed the part where you said you didn't use .c_str(), so I am just deleting my comment

Comment: @NeelBasu, one of the disadvantages of `printf` is that is isn't type safe. There's no way to overload it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because one possible outcome of undefined behaviour is that the program does what you intend. You don't need to look any further than this. Undefined behaviour is something that you simply avoid rather than trying to understand its manifestation in one particular compiler.

Comment: It actually doesn't "work" according to my testing -- that is, if by "work" you mean "it prints "12345678" to the console."  For me, it prints junk, just as I would expect.

Comment: @John According to the person asking the question, behaviour differs on 32 and 64 bit targets. But since this is UB, anything can happen.

Answer (score 9):

The reason would seem to be that in Visual Studio’s implementation of `std::string`, the first member is a `char*`. Passing the `string` by value copies this pointer (as well as the other data members) onto the stack, and the `%s` causes `printf()` to read that `char*`—and interpret it correctly, because `string` is required to be null-terminated.

This is, of course, relying on undefined behaviour, which you shouldn’t do.

Comment: +1 Thats the thing. But a compile time type check should fail if it expects a `char*` isn't it ?

Comment: @NeelBasu how should the compiler know what a function intends to do?

Comment: Cause it will try to cast it to `char*` for `%s`

Comment: @NeelBasu no it won't try to cast it to anything. There is no type checking for variadic functions and the actual `printf` function just blindly interprets bytes as the types you tell it you gave it. It can't know what you actually sent it.

Comment: @NeelBasu: Variadic functions such as `printf()` are not (generally speaking) type-checked. Compilers try to offer diagnostics for potential format string errors, but it’s not mandated by the standard. Reading a variadic argument of the wrong type with `va_arg()` simply invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: How does this explanation fit with the reported behaviour that 32 bit program crashes and 64 bit program runs fine? Do you know how variadic functions are handled on the MS x64 ABI?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No idea. I guess it must have something to do with differences in the 32-bit and 64-bit calling conventions. But it’s not terribly important.